# how can I solve this equation

Tags: contest-math

[image: I have the Ev and the N and I want to find the t]

I know it is an easy equation but I do not remember how we solve it
I have the $Ev$ and the $N$ and I want to find the t

the thing I did is that I take the exp for the both sides of the equation then I got

$$
t=\dfrac{N^2}{\exp(Ev)}
$$
but I have a Table of the values I should get and it's wrong so how can I solve it ?

What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Use $2^{Ev}$ not $\exp(Ev)$.

Answer (score 1):

Because the log function in your equation is the log base $2$, whereas exponentiation only "undoes" the natural log, which is base $e$.

You should use powers of $2$ to undo log base $2$. That is,
$$
2^{Ev} = \frac{N^2}{t}
$$